# Get course contents using webservice

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

I am using Moodle 3.1+. I am trying to get the course contents using webservice.  I have created a course with activity 'lesson'. Now when I try to get the contents of the course using webservice 'core_course_get_contents', I am getting the following response.

```
[{"id":36,"name":" 0","visible":1,"summary":"","summaryformat":1,"modules":[{"id":18,"url":"http:\/\/localhost\/moodle\/mod\/lesson\/view.php?id=18","name":"Lesson1","instance":1,"visible":1,"modicon":"http:\/\/localhost\/moodle\/theme\/image.php\/mentornetz\/lesson\/1483338014\/icon","modname":"lesson","modplural":"Lessons","indent":0}]}]
```

But the response doesn't contain the lesson details.

Moodle API documentation says that response contains below details which is missing in my response.

```
contents list of ( 
object {
type string   //a file or a folder or external link
filename string   //filename
filepath string   //filepath
filesize int   //filesize
fileurl string  Optional //downloadable file url
content string  Optional //Raw content, will be used when type is content
timecreated int   //Time created
timemodified int   //Time modified
sortorder int   //Content sort order
userid int   //User who added this content to moodle
author string   //Content owner
license string   //Content license
}
```

Below is the response for the webservice core_course_get_course_module

```
object {
cm object {
id int   //The course module id
course int   //The course id
module int   //The module type id
name string   //The activity name
modname string   //The module component name (forum, assign, etc..)
instance int   //The activity instance id
section int   //The module section id
sectionnum int   //The module section number
groupmode int   //Group mode
groupingid int   //Grouping id
completion int   //If completion is enabled
idnumber string  Optional //Module id number
added int  Optional //Time added
score int  Optional //Score
indent int  Optional //Indentation
visible int  Optional //If visible
visibleold int  Optional //Visible old
completiongradeitemnumber int  Optional //Completion grade item
completionview int  Optional //Completion view setting
completionexpected int  Optional //Completion time expected
showdescription int  Optional //If the description is showed
availability string  Optional //Availability settings
} 
warnings  Optional //list of warnings
list of ( 
  //warning
object {
item string  Optional //item
itemid int  Optional //item id
warningcode string   //the warning code can be used by the client app to implement specific behaviour
message string   //untranslated english message to explain the warning
} 
)}
```

How can I get the contents of the course? Please help.

Comment: Well, what does their API documentation say how to do that?

Comment: @arkascha      There is not enough documentation available.

Comment: The documentation says that `core_course_get_contents` delivers the courses modules including their URL. Then probably you have to make a subsequent call to `core_course_get_course_module` to get more details about a specific module in that course. I think that is pretty obvious from the documentation at https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions

Comment: @arkascha      I have updated the question. core_course_get_course_module will give the module details not the contents of the module.

Comment: And what response _does_ that call give?

Comment: @arkascha      updated question with response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all modules support exporting their contents. According to a quick grep, I found that it's mostly limited to *resources*: book, page, file, url, ...

If you add a URL resource to your course the webservice should return its content.

Comment: If you are looking to **get resource contents** on a per-course basis, the `mod_page_get_pages_by_courses` function may be helpful. Moodle webservice docs are not well documented so this info is hard to find and took me a while, thought I'd post if someone's looking for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're talking about getting content from your **lesson** type resources. The `mod_lesson_get_page_data` function may be helpful here. It returns a whole lot of info about a page in one of your lessons. From the Moodle docs (adapted to highlight the more important info):

> Return information of a given page, including its contents.

#### Arguments

- `lessonid` (Required) - lesson instance id
- `pageid` (Required) - the page id
- `returncontents` (Default to "") - if we must return the complete page contents once rendered

**Note**: `returncontents` should be an `int`. Probably `1`, but that's not documented.

#### Response

```js
object {
page  Optional //Page fields
object {
id int   //The id of this lesson page
lessonid int   //The id of the lesson this page belongs to
prevpageid int   //The id of the page before this one
nextpageid int   //The id of the next page in the page sequence
qtype int   //Identifies the page type of this page
qoption int   //Used to record page type specific options
layout int   //Used to record page specific layout selections
display int   //Used to record page specific display selections
timecreated int   //Timestamp for when the page was created
timemodified int   //Timestamp for when the page was last modified
title string  Optional //The title of this page
contents string  Optional //The contents of this page
contentsformat int  Optional //contents format (1 = HTML, 0 = MOODLE, 2 = PLAIN or 4 = MARKDOWN)
displayinmenublock int   //Toggles display in the left menu block
type int   //The type of the page [question | structure]
typeid int   //The unique identifier for the page type
typestring string   //The string that describes this page type
} 
newpageid int   //New page id (if a jump was made)
pagecontent string  Optional //Page html content
ongoingscore string   //The ongoing score message
progress int   //Progress percentage in the lesson
contentfiles   //List of files.
list of ( 
  //File.
object {
filename string  Optional //File name.
filepath string  Optional //File path.
filesize int  Optional //File size.
fileurl string  Optional //Downloadable file url.
timemodified int  Optional //Time modified.
mimetype string  Optional //File mime type.
isexternalfile int  Optional //Whether is an external file.
repositorytype string  Optional //The repository type for external files.
} 
)answers list of ( 
  //The page answers
object {
id int   //The ID of this answer in the database
answerfiles   //List of files.
list of ( 
  //File.
object {
filename string  Optional //File name.
filepath string  Optional //File path.
filesize int  Optional //File size.
fileurl string  Optional //Downloadable file url.
timemodified int  Optional //Time modified.
mimetype string  Optional //File mime type.
isexternalfile int  Optional //Whether is an external file.
repositorytype string  Optional //The repository type for external files.
} 
)responsefiles   //List of files.
list of ( 
  //File.
object {
filename string  Optional //File name.
filepath string  Optional //File path.
filesize int  Optional //File size.
fileurl string  Optional //Downloadable file url.
timemodified int  Optional //Time modified.
mimetype string  Optional //File mime type.
isexternalfile int  Optional //Whether is an external file.
repositorytype string  Optional //The repository type for external files.
} 
)jumpto int  Optional //Identifies where the user goes upon completing a page with this answer
grade int  Optional //The grade this answer is worth
score int  Optional //The score this answer will give
flags int  Optional //Used to store options for the answer
timecreated int  Optional //A timestamp of when the answer was created
timemodified int  Optional //A timestamp of when the answer was modified
answer string  Optional //Possible answer text
answerformat int  Optional //answer format (1 = HTML, 0 = MOODLE, 2 = PLAIN or 4 = MARKDOWN)
response string  Optional //Response text for the answer
responseformat int  Optional //response format (1 = HTML, 0 = MOODLE, 2 = PLAIN or 4 = MARKDOWN)
} 
)messages list of ( 
  //The lesson generated messages
object {
message string   //Message.
type string   //Message type: usually a CSS identifier like:
                                success, info, warning, error, notifyproblem, notifyerror, notifytiny, notifysuccess
} 
)displaymenu int   //Whether we should display the menu or not in this page.
warnings  Optional //list of warnings
list of ( 
  //warning
object {
item string  Optional //item
itemid int  Optional //item id
warningcode string   //the warning code can be used by the client app to implement specific behaviour
message string   //untranslated english message to explain the warning
} 
)}
```